# Bytom transaction introduction（account management model）

Tags: blockchain

Bytom project：

Github：https://github.com/Bytom/bytom

This part is for users who send transactions in Bytom own account mode.

### 1、Build transaction

API interface build-transaction，codes[api/transact.go#L120](https://github.com/Bytom/bytom/blob/master/api/transact.go#L120)

Take transactions of standard non-BTM asset for example，BTM asset which ID are consisted of F is only as gas in this transaction.This transaction means that spends 99 specified asset to specified address，its input request's json  of built transaction are as following：

```
{
  "base_transaction": null,
  "actions": [
    {
      "account_id": "0ER7MEFGG0A02",
      "amount": 20000000,
      "asset_id": "ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff",
      "type": "spend_account"
    },
    {
      "account_id": "0ER7MEFGG0A02",
      "amount": 99,
      "asset_id": "42275aacbeda1522cd41580f875c3c452daf5174b17ba062bf0ab71a568c123f",
      "type": "spend_account"
    },
    {
      "amount": 99,
      "asset_id": "42275aacbeda1522cd41580f875c3c452daf5174b17ba062bf0ab71a568c123f",
      "address": "sm1qxe4jwhkekgnxkezu7xutu5gqnnpmyc8ppq98me",
      "type": "control_address"
    }
  ],
  "ttl": 0,
  "time_range": 0
}
```

The source code of the corresponding response object is as follows：

```
// BuildRequest is main struct when building transactions
type BuildRequest struct {
    Tx        *types.TxData            `json:"base_transaction"`
    Actions   []map[string]interface{} `json:"actions"`
    TTL       json.Duration            `json:"ttl"`
    TimeRange uint64                   `json:"time_range"`
}
```

structure fields：
- `Tx` `TxData` of transaction，reserved fields，null
- `TTL` lifetime（ms） of constructed transaction，it means utxo which is already cached cannot be used for another build transaction within that timeframe，unless the left utxo are enough to build a new transaction or it will prompt error.When`ttl`is 0，its default is 600s（5minutes）
- `TimeRange` Timestamp means the transaction wont be on chain after this blockheight（timestamp）.To avoid waiting too long when you transfer transaction due to transport delay ， transaction will expire if it's not packaged in specified TimeRange.
- `Actions` `actions`structure of transaction，all transactions are made up of action，`map`type of`interface{}`ensure the scalability of action type.Action has to contain type fields to distinguish between different action types.`action`mainly contains`input`and`output`，its detailed introduction ：
  - `input action` type：
      - issue issue asset
      - spend_account spend utxo in account mode
      - spend_account_unspent_output spend specified utxo directly
  - `output action` type：
      - control_address receive in address mode
      - control_program receive in （program） contract mode
      - retire retire asset

*Pay attention*：
- One transaction must contain an input and a output or tThe asset sum of input a has to be equal with output when building input and output，otherwise transaction will show error message as the imbalance of input and output.
- Gas：BTM asset of all inputs reduce to asset of all outputs
- The asset amount in the transaction is all in units of neu， 1 BTM = 1000 mBTM = 100,000,000neu

---

#### action introduction

`action`types when you build transaction：

issue

`issueAction`Structural source code：

```
type issueAction struct {
    assets *Registry
    bc.AssetAmount
}

type AssetAmount struct {
    AssetId *AssetID `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=asset_id,json=assetId" json:"asset_id,omitempty"`
    Amount  uint64   `protobuf:"varint,2,opt,name=amount" json:"amount,omitempty"`
}
```

construction fields：
- `assets` asset management，users dont need to set parameters
- `AssetAmount` ssetID and corresponding asset amount，need to create`AssetID`by`create-asset`，cant use the assetID of`BTM`

`json`format of `issueAction`：

```
{
  "amount": 100000000,
  "asset_id": "3152a15da72be51b330e1c0f8e1c0db669269809da4f16443ff266e07cc43680",
  "type": "issue"
}
```

an example of issue asset：
（issue`900000000`which`assetID`is`42275aacbeda1522cd41580f875c3c452daf5174b17ba062bf0ab71a568c123f`to`sm1qxe4jwhkekgnxkezu7xutu5gqnnpmyc8ppq98me`, gas is`20000000`neu of BTM asset）

```
{
  "base_transaction": null,
  "actions": [
    {
      "account_id": "0ER7MEFGG0A02",
      "amount": 20000000,
      "asset_id": "ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff",
      "type": "spend_account"
    },
    {
      "amount": 900000000,
      "asset_id": "42275aacbeda1522cd41580f875c3c452daf5174b17ba062bf0ab71a568c123f",
      "type": "issue"
    },
    {
      "amount": 900000000,
      "asset_id": "42275aacbeda1522cd41580f875c3c452daf5174b17ba062bf0ab71a568c123f",
      "address": "sm1qxe4jwhkekgnxkezu7xutu5gqnnpmyc8ppq98me",
      "type": "control_address"
    }
  ],
  "ttl": 0,
  "time_range": 0
}
```

spend_account

`spendAction`Structural source code：

```
type spendAction struct {
    accounts *Manager
    bc.AssetAmount
    AccountID   string  `json:"account_id"`
    ClientToken *string `json:"client_token"`
}

type AssetAmount struct {
    AssetId *AssetID `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=asset_id,json=assetId" json:"asset_id,omitempty"`
    Amount  uint64   `protobuf:"varint,2,opt,name=amount" json:"amount,omitempty"`
}
```

structure fields：
- `accounts` account management.users dont need to set parameters
- `AccountID` spend_account
- `AssetAmount` AssetID and corresponding asset amount
- `ClientToken` Reserved limits of users' UTXO，null

``` spendAction``json ```format of `spendAction`：

```
{
  "account_id": "0BF63M2U00A04",
  "amount": 2000000000,
  "asset_id": "ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff",
  "type": "spend_account"
}
```

transaction example is as following下：
（transfer`100000000`neu Bytom asset to `sm1qxe4jwhkekgnxkezu7xutu5gqnnpmyc8ppq98me`, gas is`20000000`neu =input BTM asset - output BTM asset）

```
{
  "base_transaction": null,
  "actions": [
    {
      "account_id": "0ER7MEFGG0A02",
      "amount": 120000000,
      "asset_id": "ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff",
      "type": "spend_account"
    },
    {
      "amount": 100000000,
      "asset_id": "ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff",
      "address": "sm1qxe4jwhkekgnxkezu7xutu5gqnnpmyc8ppq98me",
      "type": "control_address"
    }
  ],
  "ttl": 0,
  "time_range": 0
}
```

spend_account_unspent_output

`spendUTXOAction`Structural source code：

```
type spendUTXOAction struct {
    accounts *Manager
    OutputID *bc.Hash `json:"output_id"`
    ClientToken *string `json:"client_token"`
}
```

structure fields：
- `accounts` account management.users dont need to set parameters
- `OutputID` ID of  UTXO，query available UTXO by`list-unspent-outputs`，`OutputID`corresponding to`id`fields of API return results
- `ClientToken` reserved limit of UTXO，null

`json`format of `spendUTXOAction`：

```
{
  "type": "spend_account_unspent_output",
  "output_id": "58f29f0f85f7bd2a91088bcbe536dee41cd0642dfb1480d3a88589bdbfd642d9"
}
```

transaction example by spendUTXO：
（transfer`100000000`neu BTM asset to `sm1qxe4jwhkekgnxkezu7xutu5gqnnpmyc8ppq98me`by UTXO, gas = input UTXO of BTM asset - output BTM asset）

```
{
  "base_transaction": null,
  "actions": [
    {
      "output_id": "58f29f0f85f7bd2a91088bcbe536dee41cd0642dfb1480d3a88589bdbfd642d9",
      "type": "spend_account_unspent_output"
    },
    {
      "amount": 100000000,
      "asset_id": "ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff",
      "address": "sm1qxe4jwhkekgnxkezu7xutu5gqnnpmyc8ppq98me",
      "type": "control_address"
    }
  ],
  "ttl": 0,
  "time_range": 0
}
```

control_address

`controlAddressAction`Structural source code：

```
type controlAddressAction struct {
    bc.AssetAmount
    Address string `json:"address"`
}

type AssetAmount struct {
    AssetId *AssetID `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=asset_id,json=assetId" json:"asset_id,omitempty"`
    Amount  uint64   `protobuf:"varint,2,opt,name=amount" json:"amount,omitempty"`
}
```

Structure field：
- `Address` receive address，can create address by `create-account-receiver` APIinterface
- `AssetAmount`asset ID to receive and corresponding asset amount

`json`format of `controlAddressAction`：

```
{
  "amount": 100000000,
  "asset_id": "ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff",
  "address": "bm1q50u3z8empm5ke0g3ngl2t3sqtr6sd7cepd3z68",
  "type": "control_address"
}
```

Transaction example：
（transfer`100000000`neuBTM address to `sm1qxe4jwhkekgnxkezu7xutu5gqnnpmyc8ppq98me`in account mode,`control_address`type use address to receive）

```
{
  "base_transaction": null,
  "actions": [
    {
      "account_id": "0ER7MEFGG0A02",
      "amount": 120000000,
      "asset_id": "ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff",
      "type": "spend_account"
    },
    {
      "amount": 100000000,
      "asset_id": "ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff",
      "address": "sm1qxe4jwhkekgnxkezu7xutu5gqnnpmyc8ppq98me",
      "type": "control_address"
    }
  ],
  "ttl": 0,
  "time_range": 0
}
```

control_program

`controlProgramAction`Structural source code：

```
type controlProgramAction struct {
    bc.AssetAmount
    Program json.HexBytes `json:"control_program"`
}

type AssetAmount struct {
    AssetId *AssetID `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=asset_id,json=assetId" json:"asset_id,omitempty"`
    Amount  uint64   `protobuf:"varint,2,opt,name=amount" json:"amount,omitempty"`
}
```

Structure fields：
- `Program` contract script to receive asset，through `create-account-receiver` APIinterface build and receive`program`（The return results of `program` and `address` are one to one correspondence）
- `AssetAmount` AssetID to receive and corresponding asset amount

`json`format of `controlProgramAction`：

```
{
  "amount": 100000000,
  "asset_id": "ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff",
  "control_program":"0014a3f9111f3b0ee96cbd119a3ea5c60058f506fb19",
  "type": "control_program"
}
```

Transaction example：
（transfer`100000000`neu BTM  asset to `program`（one to one correspondence  with`address`）`0014a3f9111f3b0ee96cbd119a3ea5c60058f506fb19`, `control_program`type uses`program`to receive）

```
{
  "base_transaction": null,
  "actions": [
    {
      "account_id": "0ER7MEFGG0A02",
      "amount": 120000000,
      "asset_id": "ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff",
      "type": "spend_account"
    },
    {
      "amount": 100000000,
      "asset_id": "ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff",
      "control_program": "0014a3f9111f3b0ee96cbd119a3ea5c60058f506fb19",
      "type": "control_program"
    }
  ],
  "ttl": 0,
  "time_range": 0
}
```

retire

`retireAction`structural source code is as follow：

```
type retireAction struct {
    bc.AssetAmount
}

type AssetAmount struct {
    AssetId *AssetID `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=asset_id,json=assetId" json:"asset_id,omitempty"`
    Amount  uint64   `protobuf:"varint,2,opt,name=amount" json:"amount,omitempty"`
}
```

Structure field：
- `AssetAmount` asset ID to receive and corresponding asset amount

`json`format of `retireAction`：

```
{
  "amount": 900000000,
  "asset_id": "3152a15da72be51b330e1c0f8e1c0db669269809da4f16443ff266e07cc43680",
  "type": "retire"
}
```

Transaction example：
（transfer`100000000`neu BTM retired asset in account mode, `retire`retire specified amount of asset）

```
{
  "base_transaction": null,
  "actions": [
    {
      "account_id": "0ER7MEFGG0A02",
      "amount": 120000000,
      "asset_id": "ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff",
      "type": "spend_account"
    },
    {
      "amount": 100000000,
      "asset_id": "ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff",
      "type": "retire"
    }
  ],
  "ttl": 0,
  "time_range": 0
}
```

Implement the input construction of`build-transaction`，you can sent transaction by http calling，json result after the implement of constructing transaction：

```
{
  "allow_additional_actions": false,
  "raw_transaction": "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",
  "signing_instructions": [
    {
      "position": 0,
      "witness_components": [
        {
          "keys": [
            {
              "derivation_path": [
                "010100000000000000",
                "0100000000000000"
              ],
              "xpub": "de0db655c091b2838ccb6cddb675779b0a9a4204b122e61699b339867dd10eb0dbdc926882ff6dd75c099c181c60d63eab0033a4b0a4d0a8c78079e39d7ad1d8"
            }
          ],
          "quorum": 1,
          "signatures": null,
          "type": "raw_tx_signature"
        },
        {
          "type": "data",
          "value": "d174db6506e35f2decb5be148c2984bfd0f6c67f043365bf642d1af387c04fd5"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "position": 1,
      "witness_components": [
        {
          "keys": [
            {
              "derivation_path": [
                "010100000000000000",
                "0800000000000000"
              ],
              "xpub": "de0db655c091b2838ccb6cddb675779b0a9a4204b122e61699b339867dd10eb0dbdc926882ff6dd75c099c181c60d63eab0033a4b0a4d0a8c78079e39d7ad1d8"
            }
          ],
          "quorum": 1,
          "signatures": null,
          "type": "raw_tx_signature"
        },
        {
          "type": "data",
          "value": "05cdbcc705f07ad87521835bbba226ad7b430cc24e5e3f008edbe61540535419"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The source code of the corresponding response object is as follows：

```
// Template represents a partially- or fully-signed transaction.
type Template struct {
    Transaction         *types.Tx             `json:"raw_transaction"`
    SigningInstructions []*SigningInstruction `json:"signing_instructions"`

    // AllowAdditional affects whether Sign commits to the tx sighash or
    // to individual details of the tx so far. When true, signatures
    // commit to tx details, and new details may be added but existing
    // ones cannot be changed. When false, signatures commit to the tx
    // as a whole, and any change to the tx invalidates the signature.
    AllowAdditional bool `json:"allow_additional_actions"`
}
```

structure fields：
- `Transaction` about transaction informations including`TxData`and`bc.Tx`：
  - `TxData` Represents the transaction data portion shown to the user, which is visible to the user
    - `Version` transaction version
    - `SerializedSize` Size after transaction serialization
    - `TimeRange` maximum timestamp（blockheight） of submitting transaction on chain（If the transaction havent been  on chain when the blockheight reach the blockheight，the transaction will empire）
    - `Inputs` transaction inputs
    - `Outputs` transaction outputs
  - `bc.Tx` Represents the transformation structure used to process transactions in the system. This part is not visible to users, so it is not described in detail
- `SigningInstructions` signature information of transaction
  - `Position` to`input action`Location of signature
  - Data informations of `WitnessComponents` to`input action`signature，`signatures`of building transaction are`null`，no signature; If transaction signed successfully，this field will exist signature information。This field is an interface，mainly include three different types：
    - `SignatureWitness`hash the contract program of `input action` in the transaction `Template` ，then sign for hash value
      - `signatures` transaction signature（arraytype），After`sign-transaction`performed，there will be a value
      - `keys` （arraytype）Including main publickey`xpub`and derived path`derivation_path`，they can find corresponding derived privatekey`child_xprv` in signature period，then use derived key to sign
      - `key`amount of`quorum` account ，the length has to be equal to the`keys`above。If`quorum` is equal to 1，it's single signature account，or it's multi-signature account
      - `program` Data of signature，hash value of `program`is as signature data 。If`program`is empty，, then a hash is generated based on the current transaction ID and the corresponding action location of InputID，then use them as command data to construct a`program` automatically
    - `RawTxSigWitness`hash InoutID（this field is in bc.Tx） of `input action` with transaction ID of`Template`
      - `signatures` transaction signature（arraytype），After`sign-transaction`performed，there will be a value
      - `keys` （arraytype) including `xpub`and derived path`derivation_path`，you can find derived private key in their signature period`child_xprv`，then use derived private key to sign
      - `key`amount of`quorum` account，the length has to be equal to `keys`above。If`quorum` is equal to 1，it represents single signature account，or its multi-signature account
    - `DataWitness` this type doesnt need signature，verify the additional data of contract program
- `AllowAdditional`Whether to allow trading of additional data, if for `true`, then additional data will be added to the transaction, but will not affect the transaction execution `program` script, will not affect the result of the signature; If for `false`, the entire transaction as a whole to sign, any data changes will affect the signatures of the transaction

#### Estimate gas

Estimated fees interface `estimate ws-transaction - gas` is for `build -transaction` fee estimate, the results of estimation results need to be added to the `build -transaction` results, and then to sign and submit for the deal. The main process is as follows:

  `build - estimate - build - sign - submit`

估算手续费的输入请求json格式如下：

```
{
  "transaction_template": {
    "allow_additional_actions": false,
    "raw_transaction": "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",
    "signing_instructions": [
      {
        "position": 0,
        "witness_components": [
          {
            "keys": [
              {
                "derivation_path": [
                  "010100000000000000",
                  "0100000000000000"
                ],
                "xpub": "de0db655c091b2838ccb6cddb675779b0a9a4204b122e61699b339867dd10eb0dbdc926882ff6dd75c099c181c60d63eab0033a4b0a4d0a8c78079e39d7ad1d8"
              }
            ],
            "quorum": 1,
            "signatures": null,
            "type": "raw_tx_signature"
          },
          {
            "type": "data",
            "value": "d174db6506e35f2decb5be148c2984bfd0f6c67f043365bf642d1af387c04fd5"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "position": 1,
        "witness_components": [
          {
            "keys": [
              {
                "derivation_path": [
                  "010100000000000000",
                  "0800000000000000"
                ],
                "xpub": "de0db655c091b2838ccb6cddb675779b0a9a4204b122e61699b339867dd10eb0dbdc926882ff6dd75c099c181c60d63eab0033a4b0a4d0a8c78079e39d7ad1d8"
              }
            ],
            "quorum": 1,
            "signatures": null,
            "type": "raw_tx_signature"
          },
          {
            "type": "data",
            "value": "05cdbcc705f07ad87521835bbba226ad7b430cc24e5e3f008edbe61540535419"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The source code for the corresponding response object is as follows：

```
type request struct{
    TxTemplate txbuilder.Template `json:"transaction_template"`
}

// Template represents a partially- or fully-signed transaction.
type Template struct {
    Transaction         *types.Tx             `json:"raw_transaction"`
    SigningInstructions []*SigningInstruction `json:"signing_instructions"`

    // AllowAdditional affects whether Sign commits to the tx sighash or
    // to individual details of the tx so far. When true, signatures
    // commit to tx details, and new details may be added but existing
    // ones cannot be changed. When false, signatures commit to the tx
    // as a whole, and any change to the tx invalidates the signature.
    AllowAdditional bool `json:"allow_additional_actions"`
}
```

you can see related fields including `TxTemplate` in the result description of build-transaction

Call `estimate ws-transaction - gas` interface after successful return json results are as follows:

```
{
  "total_neu": 5000000,
  "storage_neu": 3840000,
  "vm_neu": 1419000
}
```

The source code for the corresponding response object is as follows：

```
// EstimateTxGasResp estimate transaction consumed gas
type EstimateTxGasResp struct {
    TotalNeu   int64 `json:"total_neu"`
    StorageNeu int64 `json:"storage_neu"`
    VMNeu      int64 `json:"vm_neu"`
}
```

The structure field is explained as follows:
- `TotalNeu`Estimated gas（neu），you can add the value to BTM asset of build-transaction by inputting action
- `StorageNeu` Gas for storing transaction

### - `VMNeu` Gas for BVM operation

Answer (score 0):

### 2、signature transaction

APIinterface sign-transaction，codes[api/hsm.go#L53](https://github.com/Bytom/bytom/blob/master/api/hsm.go#L53)

The input request for the sign transaction is in json format below：

```
{
  "password": "123456",
  "transaction": {
    "allow_additional_actions": false,
    "raw_transaction": "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",
    "signing_instructions": [
      {
        "position": 0,
        "witness_components": [
          {
            "keys": [
              {
                "derivation_path": [
                  "010100000000000000",
                  "0100000000000000"
                ],
                "xpub": "de0db655c091b2838ccb6cddb675779b0a9a4204b122e61699b339867dd10eb0dbdc926882ff6dd75c099c181c60d63eab0033a4b0a4d0a8c78079e39d7ad1d8"
              }
            ],
            "quorum": 1,
            "signatures": null,
            "type": "raw_tx_signature"
          },
          {
            "type": "data",
            "value": "d174db6506e35f2decb5be148c2984bfd0f6c67f043365bf642d1af387c04fd5"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "position": 1,
        "witness_components": [
          {
            "keys": [
              {
                "derivation_path": [
                  "010100000000000000",
                  "0800000000000000"
                ],
                "xpub": "de0db655c091b2838ccb6cddb675779b0a9a4204b122e61699b339867dd10eb0dbdc926882ff6dd75c099c181c60d63eab0033a4b0a4d0a8c78079e39d7ad1d8"
              }
            ],
            "quorum": 1,
            "signatures": null,
            "type": "raw_tx_signature"
          },
          {
            "type": "data",
            "value": "05cdbcc705f07ad87521835bbba226ad7b430cc24e5e3f008edbe61540535419"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The source code for the corresponding request object is as follows:：

```
type SignRequest struct {    //function pseudohsmSignTemplates request
    Password string             `json:"password"`
    Txs      txbuilder.Template `json:"transaction"`
}
```

The structure field is explained as follows:
- `Password` password of signature，analysis users' private key from node server according to password，then use private key to sign for transaction
- `Txs` transaction template，return result of build-transaction，its structure type is `txbuilder.Template`，you can see related fields in the description of build-transaction

`sign-transaction`The json result returned after the successful request is as follows：

```
{
  "sign_complete": true,
  "transaction": {
    "allow_additional_actions": false,
    "raw_transaction": "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",
    "signing_instructions": [
      {
        "position": 0,
        "witness_components": [
          {
            "keys": [
              {
                "derivation_path": [
                  "010100000000000000",
                  "0100000000000000"
                ],
                "xpub": "de0db655c091b2838ccb6cddb675779b0a9a4204b122e61699b339867dd10eb0dbdc926882ff6dd75c099c181c60d63eab0033a4b0a4d0a8c78079e39d7ad1d8"
              }
            ],
            "quorum": 1,
            "signatures": [
              "273d5fc4fb06909fbc2968ea91c411fd20f690c88e74284ce2732052400129948538562fe432afd6cf17e590e8645b80edf80b9d9581d0a980d5f9f859e38806"
            ],
            "type": "raw_tx_signature"
          },
          {
            "type": "data",
            "value": "d174db6506e35f2decb5be148c2984bfd0f6c67f043365bf642d1af387c04fd5"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "position": 1,
        "witness_components": [
          {
            "keys": [
              {
                "derivation_path": [
                  "010100000000000000",
                  "0800000000000000"
                ],
                "xpub": "de0db655c091b2838ccb6cddb675779b0a9a4204b122e61699b339867dd10eb0dbdc926882ff6dd75c099c181c60d63eab0033a4b0a4d0a8c78079e39d7ad1d8"
              }
            ],
            "quorum": 1,
            "signatures": [
              "0cf0beefceaf9fbf1efadedeff7aee5b38ee7a25a20d78b630b01613bc2f8c9230555a6e09aaa11a82ba68c0fc9e98a47c852dfe3de851d93f9b2b7ce256f90d"
            ],
            "type": "raw_tx_signature"
          },
          {
            "type": "data",
            "value": "05cdbcc705f07ad87521835bbba226ad7b430cc24e5e3f008edbe61540535419"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The source code for the corresponding response object is as follows：

```
type signResp struct {
    Tx           *txbuilder.Template `json:"transaction"`
    SignComplete bool                `json:"sign_complete"`
}
```

The structure field is explained below：
- Transaction Template `txbuilder. Template`after `Tx` signature  , if the signature's successful `signatures` will change from null to the value of the signature and `raw_transaction` length will be longer, because `BC. Tx` part added to verify the parameters of the signature information
To complete - 
- `SignComplete` mark whether the signature is completed，if for`true`，signature completes，or it for`false`，for single signature，it's usual wrong password of signature  while you need other signature for multi-signature.Use correct password to sign again when you fail to sign，no need to`build-transaction`again

### 3、Submit transaction

APIinterface submit-transaction，codes[api/transact.go#L135](https://github.com/Bytom/bytom/blob/master/api/transact.go#L135)

The input request to submit the transaction is in json format as follows：

```
{
  "raw_transaction": "070100020161015f1190c60818b4aff485c865113c802942f29ce09088cae1b117fc4c8db2292212ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff8099c4d599010001160014a86c83ee12e6d790fb388345cc2e2b87056a0773630240273d5fc4fb06909fbc2968ea91c411fd20f690c88e74284ce2732052400129948538562fe432afd6cf17e590e8645b80edf80b9d9581d0a980d5f9f859e3880620d174db6506e35f2decb5be148c2984bfd0f6c67f043365bf642d1af387c04fd50161015fb018097c4040c8dd86d95611a13c24f90d4c9d9d06b25f5c9ed0556ac8abd73442275aacbeda1522cd41580f875c3c452daf5174b17ba062bf0ab71a568c123f80a094a58d1d0101160014068840e56af74038571f223b1c99f1b60caaf4566302400cf0beefceaf9fbf1efadedeff7aee5b38ee7a25a20d78b630b01613bc2f8c9230555a6e09aaa11a82ba68c0fc9e98a47c852dfe3de851d93f9b2b7ce256f90d2005cdbcc705f07ad87521835bbba226ad7b430cc24e5e3f008edbe6154053541903013effffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff80bfffcb9901011600140b946646626c55a52a325c8bb48de792284d9b7200013e42275aacbeda1522cd41580f875c3c452daf5174b17ba062bf0ab71a568c123f9d9f94a58d1d01160014c8b4391bab4923a83b955170d24ee4ca5b6ec3fb00013942275aacbeda1522cd41580f875c3c452daf5174b17ba062bf0ab71a568c123f6301160014366b275ed9b2266b645cf1b8be51009cc3b260e100"
}
```

The request object for the source code is shown below：

```
type SubmitRequest struct {    //function submit request
    Tx types.Tx `json:"raw_transaction"`
}
```

The structure field is explained below：
- `Tx` transaction information after signature。`raw_transaction` in this field is not the who；e returen results of`sign-transaction`，it's `raw_transaction`field in the`transaction` of sign transaction's reture results

`submit-transaction`The json result returned after the successful request is as follows：

```
{
  "tx_id": "2c0624a7d251c29d4d1ad14297c69919214e78d995affd57e73fbf84ece361cd"
}
```

The response object corresponding to the source code is as follows：

```
type submitTxResp struct {
    TxID *bc.Hash `json:"tx_id"`
}
```

The structure field is explained below：
- `TxID` Transaction ID, which displays the information when the transaction is submitted to the transaction pool, otherwise indicates that the transaction failed